# Tablesorter.js doesn't sort table as expected

Tags: jquery, html, table, tablesorter

I have implemented table sorting with the help of jquery [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com). Everything works fine, except that one of the row in one the column is not sorting properly. I tried all options mentioned in the table sorter website.

[image: tablesorter demo]

```
<apex:datatable value="{!projectAssetsWrapperList}" var="a" id="theaddrs" styleClass="tablesorter">
       <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.GSD_SRM_Assets_Table_Task_Type}" width="90px">
         <apex:outputText value="{!a.tasktypewrap}" />
       </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.GSD_SRM_Assets_Table_Sent_to_Click}" width="90px">
         <apex:outputText value="{!a.senttoclickwrap}" />
       </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.GSD_SRM_Assets_Table_Planned_Asset_Product_Description}" width="240px">
         <apex:outputText value="{!a.plannedAsstProdDescwrap}" />
       </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.GSD_SRM_Assets_Table_Planned_Asset_Serial_Number}" width="190px">
         <apex:outputText value="{!a.plannedAsssetSrnowrap}" />
       </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.GSD_SRM_Assets_Table_Planned_Asset_Product_Number}" width="190px">
         <apex:outputText value="{!a.plannedAssetPrnowrap}" />
       </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.GSD_SRM_Assets_Table_Installed_Asset_Serial_Number}" width="180px">
         <apex:outputText value="{!a.installedAssetSrnowrap}" />
       </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.GSD_SRM_Assets_Table_Installed_Asset_Product_Number}" width="190px">
         <apex:outputText value="{!a.installedAssetPrnowrap}" />
       </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.GSD_SRM_Assets_Table_Installation_date}" width="110px">
         <apex:outputText value="{!a.installationdatewrap}" /> 
       </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.GSD_SRM_Assets_Table_Subtask_Name}" width="200px">
         <apex:commandLink value="{!a.subtasknamewrap}" action="{!loadProjectTask}" target="_blank">
           <apex:param assignTo="{!projectTaskId}" value="{!a.subtaskidwrap}" name="taskId"/>                                                                             
         </apex:commandLink>
       </apex:column>
       <apex:column headerValue="{!$Label.GSD_SRM_Assets_Table_Resource_Type}" width="120px">
         <apex:outputText value="{!a.resourceType}" /> 
       </apex:column>
       </apex:dataTable>
```

[image]

Comment: As Ilya suggests, the most likely cause is that the "Subtask Name" that sorts incorrectly is different in some way i.e. the problem is with the data not the code. Use your browser's "Inspect" feature to see the exact text - HTML merges spaces so extra spaces would be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I can reproduce your bag:

You are displaying your text as a link. If you have space between words - they will be changed to underscore symbols.
If you refer to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) , you can see that space is `&#32` and underscore is `&#95`.

Thats why tablesorter places `Letter B` before `Letter_A`.

Try to inspect your table elements in table and compare they innerHtmls:

```
<a href="http://example.com">
    Letter B
</a>

<a href="http://example.com">
    Letter_A
</a>
```

Comment: Check page source, you also could have couple of spaces, but browser displays only one

Comment: all the  values  ''Asset explorer Subtask 1 Test'' in the table are getting from single variable so there will not be any changes. I also checked it but i didn't find any changes

Comment: I've checked tablesorter, it works from the box. library sorts lines by td values. could you find a way to attach your page source?

Comment: hi lepesh i have added my source code pls go trou it once...

Comment: I mean page source. in firefox yon can click right button on page and select view page source. I'm curious what page stores itself.

Comment: i have added the source code...